# If else statement with string JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, string

I am designing a page where can display score when the users make their choices.

However, this code seems not working and does not show any result in the 'score' field. 
My Html code:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <div>
      <input list="typeList" name="type" id="type">
      <datalist id="typeList">
        <option value="basketball">
        <option value="soccer">
        <option value="table tenis">
      </datalist>
    </div>
  </td>

  <td><input type="text" id="score" name="score" autocomplete="off"></td>
</tr>
```

My Script is below:

```
var type = document.getElementById("type");
var score = document.getElementById("score");

if (type === 0) {
  score.value = 0;
} else if (type === 'basketball') {
  score.value = 1;
} else if (type === 'soccer') {
  score.value = 2;
} else if (type === 'table tenis') {
  score.value = 3;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code line by line in a debugger? What is the value of `type`? What is the *type* of `type`?

Comment: `document.getElementById()` (as many other DOM functions) returns a DOM `Element`. Not sure why you're expecting an integer or a string.

Comment: Do you have any eventhandlers? Because the script executes right away and only once and both input-fields are empty. You have to include the script in a function and append an eventhandler to a button for example.

Comment: your script runs when the page loads, so, I guess nothing has been entered - javascript doesn't "just know" you want to run this code every time you make a change to `type` - you have to tell it to do so

Comment: when are you invoking `javascript` after selecting the type?

Comment: minimal change to your code - https://jsfiddle.net/usg7otnb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Jquery in this, The mistake you made is, there is no watch for the event.

```js
$('#type').on('input',function(e){
     var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
var score = document.getElementById("score"); 
if (type === 0) { score.value = 0; } 
else if (type === 'basketball') { score.value = 1; } 
else if (type === 'soccer') { score.value = 2; } 
else if (type === 'table tenis') { score.value = 3; }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div>
      <input list="typeList" name="type" id="type">
      <datalist id="typeList">
        <option value="basketball">
        <option value="soccer">
        <option value="table tenis">
      </datalist>
    </div>
  </td>

  <td><input type="text" id="score" name="score" autocomplete="off"></td>
</tr>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
var type = document.getElementById("type");
//...
```

here should be `var type = document.getElementById("type").value;`

and also

```
if (type === 0) {
```

to

```
if (type === "0") {
```

Comment: see `"0"===0` is false.

Answer (score 0):

You were able to access the element. You just need to use the `value` attribute of the element. You need to add the event `change` with dropdown so that it can bind the data in the `score` textbox when index is changed.

```js
var type = document.getElementById("type");
var score = document.getElementById("score");

type.addEventListener('change', function() { 
     if (type.value === 0) {
      score.value = 0;
    } else if (type.value === 'basketball') {
      score.value = 1;
    } else if (type.value === 'soccer') {
      score.value = 2;
    } else if (type.value === 'table tennis') {
      score.value = 3;
    }
});
```

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <div>
      <input list="typeList" name="type" id="type">
      <datalist id="typeList">
        <option value="basketball">
        <option value="soccer">
        <option value="table tennis">
      </datalist>
    </div>
  </td>

  <td><input type="text" id="score" name="score" autocomplete="off" ></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a event listener (or two, one for change and one for input) and then wrap your code in a function:

```js
var type = document.getElementById("type");
var score = document.getElementById("score");

type.addEventListener("change", function() {
    myFunction(type.value);
});

type.addEventListener("input", function() {
    myFunction(type.value);
});

var myFunction = function(type) {
  if (type === 0) {
    score.value = 0;
  } else if (type === 'basketball') {
    score.value = 1;
  } else if (type === 'soccer') {
    score.value = 2;
  } else if (type === 'table tenis') {
    score.value = 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <div>
      <input list="typeList" name="type" id="type">
      <datalist id="typeList">
        <option value="basketball">
        <option value="soccer">
        <option value="table tenis">
      </datalist>
    </div>
  </td>

  <td><input type="text" id="score" name="score" autocomplete="off"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your if it should be

```
type.value
```

to get the value of the input box. Also when are you running the script?

Answer (score 0):

```
// you forgot to attach the value property of the type element
var typeValue = document.getElementById("type").value; 
// the result for typeValue is allways a string or undefined

var scoreElement = document.getElementById("score");

// a swtich case is more efficient here
swtich(typeValue){
  case 'basketball':
    scoreElement.value = 1;
    break;
  case 'soccer':
    scoreElement.value = 2:
    break;
  case 'table tenis'
    scoreElement.value = 3;
    break;
  default:
    sourceElement.value = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with pure JavaScript along with jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4oyrw61w/

```
document.getElementById('type').addEventListener('input', function () {
    var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
    var score = document.getElementById("score");

    if (type === '0') {
        score.value = 0;
    } else if (type === 'basketball') {
      score.value = 1;
    } else if (type === 'soccer') {
      score.value = 2;
    } else if (type === 'table tenis') {
      score.value = 3;
    }
 });
```